# Angular: Why is HTML2Canvas taking so long to take a screenshot?

Tags: angular, typescript, screenshot, primeng, html2canvas

I need to take an image of my current HTML state once a user clicks save on a pop-up and then store it in a database. For this purporse I am using HTML2Canvas, and I call the function on the close event of the dialog, primeng dyanmic dialog component.
The problem is that it takes too long to execute HTML2Canvas and it also halts the screen while it's execution.
Is there any alternative library I should use?
or is there
any way I can speed up this process
Close the dialog while the process runs in the background

Note: I am using Angular 14.2.10

Following is the code I am trying to use

```
@ViewChild("screen", { static: true }) screenRef: ElementRef<any>;

dialogRef.onClose.subscribe(data => {
  if (data) {
     this.capture()
  }
});

capture(){
const dimensions = this.screenRef.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect();
let current = this
**html2canvas(this.screenRef.nativeElement, {
width: dimensions.width,
height: dimensions.height,
useCORS: true,
})**.then(canvas => {
this.layoutImage = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
});
}
```

**Note: It takes too long execute the bold/highlighted part**
I also tried to execute it with a very simple div but still facing the same issue

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score -1):

You can try couple of tweaks to reduce image size and speed up the processing

1. Use scale values, i.e - html2canvas.default(document.body, {
   scale: 0.1,
2. Pass quality param - canvas.toDataURL("image/png", 1.0),
3. On dialog close event, use angular web worker to run all heavy liftings in background thread.

Cheers!

Comment: Hi, I tried scaling and reducing the image quality but it didn't speed up the process.

Comment: Double checking my implementation with yours, there are little differences. I used the 'document' as target and to get height/width -  html2canvas.default(document.body, {
      scale: 0.1,
      useCORS: true,
      allowTaint: false,
      windowWidth: document.body.scrollWidth,
      windowHeight: document.body.scrollHeight
    }..... I also saved the image as png - canvas.toDataURL("image/png", 1.0)....You might like to check these areas. Thanks!